# Recommended connection pool size for HikariCP

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, hikaricp

As written in HikariCP [docs](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing#connections--core_count--2--effective_spindle_count) the formula for counting connection pool size is `connections = ((core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)`. But which core count is this: my app server or database server?
For example: my is app running on 2 CPUs, but database is running on 16 CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

This is Kevin's formula for connection pool size, where cores and spindles (you can tell is is an old formula) are the database server's.

This assumes that the connections are kept fairly busy. If you have transactions with longer idle times, you might need to make the pool bigger.

In the end, only trial and error can find the ideal pool size.

Comment: As I wrote, the database server's.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is from [PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) which is related to database cores/server

> database server only has so many resources, and if you don't have enough connections active to use all of them, your throughput will generally improve by using more connections.

Notice that this formula may be [outdated](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228663/what-is-effective-spindle-count) (comment by @mustaccio)

> That wiki page was last updated nearly 5 years ago, and the advice in question is even older. I/O queue depth might be more relevant today than the number of spindles, even if the latter are actually present